# kube-dns container crashes due to "Failed to create a kubernetes client: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied"

Tags: kubernetes, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-1.16

In a GKE cluster with version 1.16.6-gke.12 from the rapid channel the `kubedns` container of the `kube-dns-...` pods of the `kube-dns` service fail permanently due to

```
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   F0315 20:43:54.029575 1 server.go:61] Failed to create a kubernetes client: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: permission denied
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029539 1 dns.go:48] version: 1.15.8
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029524 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --vmodule=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029517 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --version="false"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029512 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --v="2"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029506 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029500 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --profiling="false"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029495 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --nameservers=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029490 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029485 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029479 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --log-dir=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029466 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029460 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029439 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029432 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --initial-sync-timeout="1m0s"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029426 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029419 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --federations=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029412 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029404 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029398 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029390 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --config-period="10s"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029382 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029373 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --config-map=""
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029363 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --config-dir="/kube-dns-config"
kubedns     15 Mar 2020, 21:43:54   I0315 20:43:54.029288 1 flags.go:52] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
```

Is there a workaround this. Where should I report this?

Version information:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:14:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16+", GitVersion:"v1.16.6-gke.12", GitCommit:"74e2d6182ba7947983ec6d59776c38c53b086a37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-27T18:38:03Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: Did you manage to find any workaround ?

Comment: @MaggieO No. Last thing I did was trying the command for cert-manager in your answer with the result in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60697549/kube-dns-container-crashes-due-to-failed-to-create-a-kubernetes-client-open-v?noredirect=1#comment107478139_60705890. No success.

Comment: I was facing this on kubernetes version 1.21. This worked out for me - https://github.com/aws/amazon-eks-pod-identity-webhook/issues/8#issuecomment-531343852

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New GKE clusters now use Kubernetes version **1.14** by default. GKE now offers Kubernetes **1.17** in preview, which requires requesting access from Google Cloud to use. Analogically if there will be release of GKE which will use Kubernetes **1.18** - which solves problem with service account (kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes - "Fixes service account token admission error in clusters that do not run the service account token controller- [admission](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87029)) - this GKE version will at the same time solve your problem.

See: [kubernetes-1.18](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/), [new-kubernetes-release](https://www.stackrox.com/post/2020/03/what-is-new-in-kubernetes-1.18/).

Comment: Thanks for you input. I'm experiencing this issue on GKE where a manipulation of `manifests` isn't possible afaik. I tried both `true` and `false` for `automountServiceAccountToken` (on the `spec.template.spec` of the `kube-dns` deployment), but the newly created pods fail due to the same issue (container `kubedns` crashing due to the same error).

Comment: I have updated my answer, please take a look at point 3. Does it help ?

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I created the clusterrolebinding successfully for the service account I'm using and another one for the service account kube-system:kube-dns as well. The issue still occurs. I also deleted the kube-dns deployment which is then recreated by GKE: same result. Regarding the command order, the hint is referrring to (a the cert-manager installation command): it doesn't seem to matter because as soon as the cluster accepts `kubectl` commands the `kube-dns` deployment is already started.

Comment: You will have to wait for release gke for v1.18. Take a look: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/ - "Fixes service account token admission error in clusters that do not run the service account token controller (#87029, @liggitt)". Do you need some more information ?

Comment: Thanks. If you reference the issue and the k8s version in the question with the explanation why it solves the problem, I can mark it solved.

Comment: Since this seems to be a bug which has a fix, it'd be nice if it'd be backported to 1.17 afaik. Do you have a reference of the issue? Would I report this against Kubernetes or Google Kubernetes Engine?